# Scalar LMMSE based on N Observations

Tags: normal-distribution, estimation, covariance

Supposing I have a Gaussian Random Variable X of zero mean and unit variance and N samples of the variable. On each sample these is also Noise W that is a Gaussian Random Variable with zero mean and unit variance. The result is Y= X + W. So the y vector consists of N observations y<sub>1</sub>=x+w<sub>1</sub>, y<sub>2</sub>=x+w<sub>2</sub>, ..., y<sub>n</sub>=x+w<sub>n</sub>. I have to plot (scatterplot) estimation of X for each sample by applying a simple LMMSE and also estimating the covariance matrices instead of using cov() for my estimations. The estimation of X equals the sum of all samples multiplied by a weight each.

\begin{align}
      \ x_{estimation} = \frac{cov(x,y_1)}{\sigma_{y_{1}}^2}y_1 + \frac{cov(x,y_2)}{\sigma_{y_{2}}^2}y_2+...+\frac{cov(x,y_n)}{\sigma_{y_{n}}^2}y_n\\
      \end{align}

How do I estimate each Covariance and what does it mean to plot estimation for each sample?